# mvn dependency:tree does not list dependencies of a dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a project that has a dependency, say X.jar, which has its own dependency Y.jar. When I include X.jar as a dependency in my project I expect that all the dependencies of X.jar be available to me in my project.

Indeed this is the case with other dependencies. When I run mvn dependency:tree it lists dependencies and their dependencies as expected but it fails to list any dependencies for X.jar.

X.jar is a custom jar from a project I wrote (I have indeed added X.jar to the local repo) so perhaps the problem lies there. When I run mvn dependency:tree on the X project it lists all dependencies correctly.

I have no idea how to debug this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code which X uses to depend on Y (i.e. the `<dependency>` element of the POM from X).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably that the pom.xml of your X.jar is not properly installed in your repository.

When you install a jar "by hand" in your repo :use the option `-DpomFile="<path_to_your_pom>"` .

If you don't do that : maven will create (and **install !!!**)  an ultra-simple pom.xml for you (and of course it don't contains any data about dependencies).

More about installing a custom jar [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Oh indeed! (note that while this makes sense I have not tested it as I have since installed from the project itself after making some other changes)